# A stick of length 1 is broken at a uniformly random point, yielding two pieces. Find CDF for ratio of smaller to larger piece

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I've found many solutions online to this question, but they all make an algebraic move that I cannot understand. For instance, if $R=\frac{X}{1-X}$,

$$P(R ≤ r) = P(X ≤ r(1-X)) = P(X ≤ r/(1 +r)).$$

How does the second expression equal the third?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics stack exchange.  You can use MathJax to improve the equations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What they have done is this:
$$
X\leq r(1-X)\\
X\leq r-rX\\
X+rX\leq r\\
X(1+r)\leq r\\
X\leq \frac{r}{1+r}
$$
where $1+r$ is positive, so dividing by it is valid and doesn't change the direction of the inequality.